# Mobile Phone Operating System

Tags: blackberry-10

Is it possible to to replace a mobile phones operating system from Android OS, v4.2 (Jelly Bean) to Blackberry os 10? and if so are there any instructions?

Comment: This site is for programming or programmer's tools related questions, not general computer or software questions. The [help] can provide more info on the types of questions that are appropriate here. You might be able to get help on another [se] site such as [su], but please be sure to read each site's guidelines before posting there. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Not the right place to ask this, but I'll answer anyway. No, you can't. BlackBerry 10 is closed OS, and you don't have access to modify drivers and other stuff needed. Probably even requires specific peaces of hardware.